# Cannot load local json file using axios and vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, localhost, axios

I keep getting a 404 not found when trying to load a json file. At first I had the file in `scr/static/` then I moved it into the root of the directory in a folder called `data`. I've tried multiple things and no luck. Not sure if I can't use `mounted` or what but all the examples I find seem like I'm doing it right.

```
<template>
 <div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import axios from 'axios'

 const url = 'http://localhost:8080/data/releases.json';

 export default {
  name: 'Releases',
  data () {
   return {
    releases: []
   }
  },
  mounted () {

   axios.get(url).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
   })
  }
}


</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Since you're using a bundler, I assume *webpack*, things arent hosted in their proper directories like you'd think. You'd need to spin up a server and serve that JSON file if you'd want to do it that way. However, is there any reason why you wouldn't just `import data from '../data/releases.json'` it?

Comment: I've tried doing that but I still get the error and also from what I've read it looks like axios needs the full path when it's local.

Comment: Show your node.js server code if using it? Also, what domain you are serving this UI from?